# Observing LiveData from Room in ViewModel triggers UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am observing a list from `Room` database in my `ViewModel`.

My `ViewModel` code looks something like below:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private lateinit var _questionList: List<Question>
    val questionList
        get() = _questionList

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onCreate(owner)
        
        repository.getAllQuestions().observe(owner::getLifecycle) {
            _questionList = it
            Log.d("ViewModel", "QuestionList: $_questionList")
        }
    }
}
```

`repository.getAllQuestions()` returns list of Questions as `LiveData` from `Room`.

I am using this `ViewModel`'s questionList in `Fragment`.
And my `Fragment` looks something like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AllQuestionsFragment : BindingFragment<AllQuestionsFragmentBinding>() {

    override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> ViewBinding
        get() = AllQuestionsFragmentBinding::inflate

    private val viewModel: AllQuestionsViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycle.addObserver(viewModel)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.progressQuestions.max = viewModel.questionList.size
    }
}
```

My problem is anytime I try to use that list in `Fragment`, I get crash saying the `questionList` in `ViewModel` is not initialized (`UninitializedPropertyAccessException`).

If I do not use that list in `Fragment`, the `Log` statement in `ViewModel` executes successfully and prints the list from the database.

Also, if I add some delay before accessing that list in `Fragment`, then it works too. I can add delay, but not sure if that is optimum because I am not sure about the cause and how much delay is needed.

I also tried using `repository.getAllQuestions().asFlow().collect {}` instead of observe; and also mobing that block of code inside the `init` block in `ViewModel`, but got the same issue.

What I am missing here?

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Try by initializing  _questionList variable, private var _questionList: List<Question> = listOf()

Comment: This initializes the list but again it is still empty by the time it is used in the fragment. So, got rid of the UninitializedPropertyAccessException but got IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Where are you getting IndexOutOfBoundException?

Comment: I have other codes that uses questions inside the questionList in fragment. For simplicity, I just put one line of usage here in the question, which only requires the size.

Comment: If you are accessing any static index then put check if(viewModel.questionList.size>accessibleIndex){// Put Your code which will use question from accessibleIndex position}

Answer (score 0):

`repository.getAllQuestions()` already returning `LiveData` So just return the same `LiveData` to UI layer i.e Fragment and observe it there . Also You do not need `DefaultLifecycleObserver` for this unless you want to handle some specific case . Load the data inside `init` of `ViewModel`

```
@HiltViewModel
class AllQuestionsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {
     var _questionListLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<Question>> = repository.getAllQuestions()
}
```

Now you can just Observe `_questionListLiveData` in the Fragment . Query returning `LiveData` runs on background thread so you do not need a Co routine for this .

Comment: I have other codes in the viewmodel which requires the owner, that is why I am using DefaultLifecycleObserver. I wanted to keep the simple list in viewmodel and work with some logic there to provide a single question to the fragment when fragment triggers a function in viewModel.

Comment: I was converting livedata to flow and collect in ViewModel and copied that code here and forgot to remove the coroutine line. I edited it. Thank you.